# Recording is not resumed if microphone has been plugged in during phone call

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-audio, avaudiosession

Currently I am developing application on iOS that records audio files with a help of `AudioQueue`. In order to handle interruption like phone calls, alarm clock etc. I register callback for `notification`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(audioSessionDidChangeInterruptionType:)
                                             name:AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification object:self.session];
```

and handle it appropriately

```
- (void)audioSessionDidChangeInterruptionType:(NSNotification *)notification 
{
    AVAudioSessionInterruptionType interruptionType = (AVAudioSessionInterruptionType)[[[notification userInfo]
                                                                                    objectForKey:AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey] unsignedIntegerValue];

    if (AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeBegan == interruptionType)
    {
        //handle beginning or interruption
    }
    else if (AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeEnded == interruptionType)
    {
        //handle end or interruption
    } 
}
```

Everything works fine, whenever user gets phone call, recording is paused and then resumed after finishing phone call. But there is one, tiny detail that breaks all of this. If I plug in or plug out `microphone` during `phone call`, recording is not resumed. It is not resumed because when I finish phone call, method `audioSessionDidChangeInterruptionType` with `AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeEnded` is not invoked. For application, interruption never ends.

I had an idea to start `NSTimer` when interruption begins and than check every seconds if phone call has been already finished, but it has 2 drawbacks:

1. It is *very* dirty
2. It doesn't solve every case i.e. alarm clock.

Have you ever encountered this issue? If yes, did you find a way around it?

I use iPhone 5S with iOS8.

Comment: You said microphone. Do you mean headphone? Because the jack on iPhone is for headphones. And some headphones have extra wiring to handle mic input.  But I don't think you have plug in a straight microphone without some type of adapter.

Comment: Actually, I meant headset.

Comment: @JohnnyFloyd, did you get an answer to the question or solve it in any way?

Answer (score 0):

From Apple [iOS Human Interface Guidelines on Sound](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Sound.html):

> Users use headsets and headphones to hear sounds privately and to free
>   their hands. Regardless of whether these accessories are wired or
>   wireless, users have specific expectations for the user experience.
>
> When users plug in a headset or headphones, or connect to a wireless
>   audio device, they intend to continue listening to the current audio,
>   but privately. For this reason, they expect an app that is currently
>   playing audio to continue playing without pause.
>
> When users unplug a headset or headphones, or disconnect from a
>   wireless device (or the device goes out of range or turns off), they
>   don’t want to automatically share what they’ve been listening to with
>   others. For this reason, they expect an app that is currently playing
>   audio to pause, allowing them to explicitly restart playback when
>   they’re ready.

Given that you will be hard press to find a clean solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was afraid that It would be hard problem to solve. I understand why It works that way for playing audio, but I think this rule should not be applied to audio recording. You may not want other people to listen what are you listening on your device, but they can _hear_ what your device is recording anyway, so unplugging microphone/headset does not put your privacy into risk. I thought for a minute that changing audio session category from `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` to `AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord` can change something, but it didn't.